# iOS: How to render a new view from a button click

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just learning iOS development and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this.

I created a two tabbed todo app. One screen showcases the list of todos, whilst the other just handles todo inputs

On the input tab I'm using a TextField and a button to add todos, but I'd like the list view to be rendered after each new addition.

tab2 -> enter todo -> press button -> render tab1

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: In the button click method, set the `selectedIndex` of the tabBarController to 0 -> which will show the first tab.

Comment: @VidyaMurthy that was exactly what I wanted, thanks 

Comment: Glad you've got it how you wanted. I should add that a more idiomatic solution would be to not use tabs at all, but use a button on the top right of the navbar (say), which launches a modal view controller to enter the todo. Hit done and the modal would slide away and you're back at the first view controller.

Comment: That's a good point @VicSmith, I'll try to implement that.